# How do i get the value from array and assign to view in zend frame work

Tags: php, zend-framework

iam executing a stored procedure in php and iam returning an array

```
       ["record"]=>
   array(1175) {
   [0]=>
array(20) {
  ["Col1"]=>
  string(1) "Mode"
  ["col2"]=>
  string(16) "type"
   }
   }
```

how do i get the  col1 and col2 values from the  array and assign it to the view 
.what should i say

```
$view-.results = $result_val['record'];
$view->col1 = ????
$view->col2 = ????
```

Answer (score 3):

From the controller you assign data to the view using:

```
$this->view->myData = "something";
```

Then in the view phtml file:

```
echo $this->myData;
```

So in the controller its $this->view and in the view its $this.

In your case assuming your array is called $records:

```
$this->view->records = $records;
```

then in your view:

```
foreach($this->records as $record){
   echo 'Col1 = ' . $record['Col1']. "<BR />";
   echo 'Col2 = ' . $record['Col2']. "<BR />";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @lznogood: How do i assign value of "Something " from an array that is my problem

Comment: @Someone if that still doesnt help I suggest you post more code and make use of the code formater. Its the 001001 button when you post/edit your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller:

```
$this->view->record=$record[0]
```

In the View:

```
echo $this->record["col1"]
echo $this->record["col2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am doing like this**

```
// this is to set the view files path

$view = $this->view;
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../themes/" . $siteName."/views/helpers");
$view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../themes/" . $siteName."/views/scripts"); // or addBasePath(), if you prefer
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
```

**Then assign the value from controller**

```
$this->view->featuredProducts = $featuredProducts;
```

then, In the view file.....

```
<?php foreach($this->featuredProducts As $fpIndex=>$featuredProduct){?>
-----
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use assign method to add an array of variables, for example

```
$array = array('var1' => 'val1', 'var2' => 'val2');
$this->view->assign($array);
```

If you do above in view, you can use

```
$this->view->var1
$this->view->var2
```

etc

Hope this helps.